# Adding a class object to 3 different list but the values are not changing?

Tags: vb.net

I am having a weird problem, maybe it's an easy fix but I cannot figure it out. I created a class and then I create an object for that class. I change the values of the variables inside and add it to a different list, but the values are all the same across different lists.
My explanation is hard to understand, so hopefully, the code makes it easier to understand.

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Gender As String
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Human As New Person
    Human.Name = "Amanda"
    Human.Gender = "Female"

    Dim List1 As New List(Of Person)
    Dim List2 As New List(Of Person)
    Dim List3 As New List(Of Person)

    'Add to list 1
    Human.Name = "Ashley"
    List1.Add(Human)

    'Add to list 2
    Human.Name = "Amy"
    List2.Add(Human)

    'Add to list 3
    Human.Name = "Ana"
    List3.Add(Human)

    MsgBox("List1 Person Name: " & List1(0).Name & vbNewLine &
           "List2 Person Name: " & List2(0).Name & vbNewLine &
           "List3 Person Name: " & List3(0).Name)
End Sub
```

Here's what the result looks like:

[image]

Shouldn't each of those have different names like the ones I set?

They're all the same name. I changed the name before adding it into the list, and when I get the value, they're from different list as well. I don't understand why the results would be all the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **only one Human object instance** in that code. Adding it to a list neither creates a new object nor makes a copy. You still have the *same object instance* in all three lists, such that by the time of the `MsgBox()` call the `Name` property of that one instance has changed to `Ana`.

You want to do this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim List1 As New List(Of Person)
    Dim List2 As New List(Of Person)
    Dim List3 As New List(Of Person)

    List1.Add(New Human With {.Name = "Ashley", .Gender = "Female"})
    List2.Add(New Human With {.Name = "Amy", .Gender = "Female"})
    List3.Add(New Human With {.Name = "Ana", .Gender = "Female"})

    MsgBox($"List1 Person Name: {List1(0).Name}{vbCrLf}List2 Person Name: {List2(0).Name}{vbCrLf}List3 Person Name: {List3(0).Name}")
End Sub
```

You could also use a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/) to further simplify the code, but that might further confuse the difference between a reference, a variable, and an instance for you, and for one item it's not much better than the `.Add()` call. But let's show something like that for fun, and make better use of the `List` type while we're at it:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim people As New List(Of Person) From {
        New Human With {.Name = "Ashley", .Gender = "Female"},
        New Human With {.Name = "Amy", .Gender = "Female"},
        New Human With {.Name = "Ana", .Gender = "Female"}
    }

    MsgBox($"First Person Name: {people(0).Name}{vbCrLf}Second Person Name: {people(1).Name}{vbCrLf}Third Person Name: {people(2).Name}")
End Sub
```

As a side note, a [`Structure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/structure-statement), rather than a Class, would produce the behavior you expected in the question. However, many consider mutable structures like that as poor practice; stick with the Class.

Comment: Ahh man, should've paid more attention in programming class. Thank you for the explanation.